# Dart Polymer element with published property: how to avoid self-notification

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, observable

I've a custom Polymer element with a published property `inputValue`.

The component listen for `inputValue` changes, and when it changes report the new value to an internal logic.

The same is done in the opposite direction: the element listen for internal logic changes and set the new value to the `inputValue`.

When the new value is set to `inputValue` this make the observe system notify all the listeners, but the element is itself a listener.

I want to avoid that the element is notified about changes made by itself.

Here the custom element Dart code:

```dart
@CustomTag("codemirror-input")
class CodemirrorInput extends PolymerElement {

  @published
  String mode;

  @published
  String inputValue;

  CodemirrorInput.created() : super.created();

  void ready() {

    Map options = {
      'mode':  mode
    };

    GradeCodeMirror editor = new GradeCodeMirror.fromElement(
        $['codemirror'], options: options);

    onPropertyChange(this, #inputValue, (){
      editor.setOption("value", inputValue);
    });

    editor.onChange.listen((_){
      inputValue = editor.getDoc().getValue();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It is still hard to grasp for me what is going on here. Can't you just update the `value` from your code and let Polymer resolve the updating? What makes `editor.onChange.listen` fire?

Comment: Codemirror is an external library that wraps a DIV and make it a source code editor providing syntax highlight. I'm using a porting to Dart of that JS library. The editor.onChange.listen is fired by the codemirror editor when the user modify the code in the source code editor.

Comment: Is this the same `value` is bound to?

Comment: I'm using the value property (now fixed and rename inputValue) as bridge for external data-binding.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why `inputValueChanged` fires at all if the value didn't actually change, I thought it fires only when the old value and new value differ.
But if it really doesn't work this way you can check this yourself

```
editor.onChange.listen((_){
  var val = editor.getDoc().getValue();
  if(inputValue != val) {
    inputValue = val;
  }
});
```

```dart
onPropertyChange(this, #inputValue, (){
  editor.setOption("value", inputValue);
});
```

can be simplified by adding a method to the element

```dart
void inputValueChanged(oldValue, newValue) {
  editor.setOption("value", inputValue);
}
```

This method is called every time `inputValue` changes.